# Thread.Start() vs BackgroundWorker

Tags: .net, multithreading

what is the difference between create thread using thread.start and using background worker ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about .NET a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) uses a thread from the [thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.start.aspx) (it doesn't create a new thread but it might block if there are no threads available in the pool) while [Thread.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.start.aspx) starts a new managed thread.

Answer (score 3):

A background worker uses a thread from the thread pool. Thread pool threads are regular threads but as they are reused the cost of starting them is amortized. As the cost of starting a thread may be significant the thread pool is ideal for short running tasks.

Answer (score 1):

the big advantage of BackgroundWorker is that you can call GUI code in it's ProgressChanged event handler.